# How to get x values as a pair on a dataframe in scala?

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, operation

I have a dataframe with **27770** entries in scala using spark. This dataframe contains only one column of integers. I want to combine this column by itshelf in order to generate a new dataframe with pairs per 2 values. I want to do this for every row in dataframe. I am trying to do this by the code below:

```
for (elem1 <- nodeDf.collect()) {
  for (elem2 <- nodeDf.collect()) {
      if(elem1 != elem2 && elem2 > elem1) {
        //get pair elem1, elem2
      }
  }
}
```

Intellij shows me an error about '>' operator says that 'cannot resolve symbol'.
What I am doing wrong? How I can get a new data frame with two columns for every combination of all values?

For example: input dataframe contains

1
2
3

I want to get a new dataframe with pairs as bellow:

1,2
1,3
2,3

I want to skip pairs like 1,1 , 2,2 or 2,1 because I have allready the 1,2 which is the same for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just do a [***carstesian* product**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@crossJoin(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) of the `DataFrame` with itself.

```
val result =
  df.as("a").crossJoin(
    df.as("b")
  ).filter(
    ($"a.id" =!= $"b.id") && ($"b.id" > $"a.id")
  )
```

The reson why your code didn't work, is because doing a `collect` on a `DataFrame` will get you an `Array[Row]` and there is not such `>` method in `Row`.
*You may fix it by transforming the `DataFrame` to a `Dataset[Int]` with `.as[Int]`, or by fetching the element of the row with `elem1.getAsInt(0)`, but...*

**DON'T DO THAT!**.
Collect returns all your distributed data to the driver, it is not only dangerous, but destroys all the purpose of Spark itself.
*Also, not to mention that doing a double `collect` of the same data is useless and expensive*.

Comment: Hi! I hava tried the following val result = nodeDf.as("a").crossJoin(nodeDf.as("b")).filter($"a.id" != $"b.id" && $"b.id" > $"a.id")
and I am getting an error:

 Error:(49, 96) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column required: Boolean

 val result = nodeDf.as("a").crossJoin(nodeDf.as("b")).filter($"a.id" != $"b.id" && $"b.id" > $"a.id")

What is wrong?

Comment: @atheodos the `!=` is incorrect in **Spark**, you need to use `=!=`. I edited my answer with the fix - sorry about that, yesterday I answered from my phone, so I could not compile and tests the code _(I have just done)_, and I always forgot about that operator difference.

Comment: Thank you Luis. I have teied your solution. It works. Now the point is which one sould I use. The operation with sql which I posted or yours? Which of them is more efficient? This is my first step with scala and Spark so I dont know the correct answer!

Comment: @atheodos as far as I understand both should translate to the same underlying execution plan, thus I would just use the one which _"looks"_ better for you - IMHO, my personal choice is to avoid as much as possible String Queries, because there is no check of anything, going further I prefer `Datasets` because they are type checked in compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to crossJoin the same ds. After you can write a where clause to returns only the row with different number between the two columns and only the row that have the ANumber less then BNumber.
This is an example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataTypes, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, Row, SparkSession}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class Test extends FunSuite { 

  test("Test spark cross join") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val rows = Seq(Row(1),Row(2),Row(3))
    val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("Number",DataTypes.IntegerType)))
    val ds = spark.createDataset(rows)(RowEncoder(schema))

    val crossJoinDs = ds.select($"Number".as("ANumber"))
      .crossJoin(ds.select($"Number".as("BNumber")))
      .where($"ANumber" =!=  $"BNumber" && $"ANumber" < $"BNumber")
      .map(r => String.valueOf(r(0))+","+String.valueOf(r(1)))(Encoders.STRING)

    crossJoinDs.show()

  }
```

that print the following output:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  1,2|
|  1,3|
|  2,3|
+-----+
```

When you write collect and iterate over the result you send all data to the drivernode. Basically you stop the distributed computation of the works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Finaly, I found it. I have to do just an sql query like bellow:

```
result.createOrReplaceTempView("pairs")
var pairsDF = result.sqlContext.sql("select * from pairs a, pairs b where a.id < b.id").toDF("id_from","id_to")
```

Result:

[image]

Result was tested for every row and found to work properly! Thank you guys.